# enzyme simulate 'click' doesn't work when it should

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using Jest and Enzyme to test out a Form component, and I'm having trouble getting the click simulation to work. For reference: `Button` is a styled rebass Button, and exists in the form like this:

```
<Button
  type="reset"
  disabled={pristine || submitting}
  onClick={() => onClose(dirty)}
>
```

Here's the test that's failing:

```
 it('should handle the onClose event', () => {
      const onCloseSpy = jest.fn();
      const renderedComponent = mount(renderFormUtil({ onClose: onCloseSpy }));
      expect(onCloseSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      console.log(renderedComponent.find(Form).props().onClose);
      renderedComponent
      .find(Button)
      .first()
      .simulate('click');
    expect(onCloseSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

What should be noted here, is that if I replace the simulate line with the following:

```
renderedComponent
  .find(Button)
  .first()
  .props()
  .onClick();
```

then suddenly my test passes. How is this possible? If the onClick prop is correct, then doesn't that mean the click event is not calling the prop correctly?

Comment: Why do you use `.find(ButtonSubmit)` in one case and `.find(Button)` in the other? I don't know what `Button` looks like, but I wouldn't expect the same result, since you are testing two different components.

Comment: Sorry, those are the same component-- I meant to get rid of the word Submit in the component name, for simplification

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if the two `.find` select the same components because each one uses a different selector. Combined with that you are using `.first()` which it's not possible to be sure about the order with the sample code.
You can try to use a more specific selector, avoiding to use `.first()` and getting the desired component just with `.find`. For that you can add an `id` for a specific `ButtonSubmit` and use a selector like:
`.find('ButtonSubmit[id="foo"]')`

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question-- There shouldn't be a ButtonSubmit. I got rid of that part of the name for the purposes of asking this question so it would be simpler, but apparently didn't do a thorough job.

They should be selecting the same element, AFAIK.